# Runtime Notice: Declaration of in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

I develop on to different systems. On of them using PHP 5.4 and on the other i have PHP version 5.5.9.

If I open my project with the 5.4 Version all is good and no error is report. But if I try to open the same project with PHP 5.5.9 I got the following error and symfony stop:

> ContextErrorException: Runtime Notice: Declaration of Event\UserBundle\Manager\EventManager::getRepository() should be compatible with Event\UserBundle\Manager\AbstractManager::getRepository($entity = NULL) in ...

Now i read that the php strict warning can be produce this error. But in my PHP.ini error settings are this:

`E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

Anyone can help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the method that you are overwriting `getRepository` is not in the same format as the base method `getRepository($entity = null)`. To stop the error (by making it compatible), just add the `$entity = null` to the method declaration.

As to the actual errors issue (not showing and then showing) I can't help you. It's possible that things have gotten more strict in the newer version. I did notice recently that a newer version wouldn't allow a function to be declared abstract in a class and then also be declared in an accompanying interface, so it is possible.

Comment: How do you rectify this error when the class lives inside the Vendors?

Comment: When the child class is in the vendor folder? If it's the child class then you can raise an issue and hope it gets sorted out and/or fork the repo and change it your self (and add your forked repository to your composer.json file) for the time being.